# Can I flip $ \left\lVert a - b \right\rVert_2 \ge \left\lVert a \right\rVert_2 - \left\lVert b \right\rVert_2$

Tags: geometry, inequality

Can I flip $ \left\lVert a - b \right\rVert_2 \ge  \left\lVert a \right\rVert_2 -  \left\lVert b \right\rVert_2$  to $\left\lVert a - b \right\rVert_2 \le  \left\lVert b \right\rVert_2 -  \left\lVert a \right\rVert_2$ using the argument of 2-norm values are positive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot. For instance, if $a\neq0$ and $b=0$, you get$$\|a\|_2=\|a-b\|_2\leqslant\|b\|_2-\|a\|_2=-\|a\|_2.$$That is, a positive number is smaller than a negative one…

Comment: My context is $a,b \in R^d$. Can we get rid of b=0 in such case?

Comment: No, since $\mathbb{R}^d$ has a null vector.